# DeepPartial: use null instead of undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typechecking, type-constraints

When applying the `DeepPartial` generic type from `utility-types` to Typescript type I notice that the type of all properties is automatically expanded to include `undefined`. I.e. a property that previous was of type `T` now become `T | undefined`.

E.g. the following code fails typechecking:

```
import { DeepPartial } from 'utility-types';

type A = { a1: number, a2: number};
type B = DeepPartial<A>;

const b: B = { a1: null };
```

Typescript playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQKarABQIa2NgGzgF84AzKCEOAcgFcZgDgYBPAWjbFQGcaBuAFCCuqOAEE4AXkRxsARgBccAHZ0QAI1RQANHIBMytZu3EhouACFpKdFlyNCAHnEA+IYIDGEFT3gblaxkkBSM6AiIzQSA).

I get it that this is what plain old `Partial` does as well. But is there a deeper reason why `| undefined` was chosen (in both cases) as opposed, e.g. to: `| null` or `| null | undefined` and is there a way I can customize the `DeepPartial` generic type so as to generate property types with `| null` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `Partial<T>` is to transform a type like `{x: number, y: string}` into a type where the properties are all optional, like `{x?: number, y?: string}`. In this case the types of the properties are `number | undefined` and `string | undefined` because `?` means the property is allowed to be missing, and `undefined` is what you get when accessing a missing property.

To get `null` instead of `undefined`, you can just take the [source code for DeepPartial](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types/blob/2ae7412a9edf12f34fedbf594facf43cf04f7e32/src/mapped-types.ts#L484) and adjust it:

```
type DeepNullable<T> = T extends Function
    ? T
    : T extends Array<infer U>
    ? _DeepNullableArray<U>
    : T extends object
    ? _DeepNullableObject<T>
    : T | null;

interface _DeepNullableArray<T> extends Array<DeepNullable<T>> {}

type _DeepNullableObject<T> = { [P in keyof T]: DeepNullable<T[P]> | null };
```

Demo:

```
type Foo = {
    foo: number,
    bar: {
        baz: Array<{ quz: string }>
        qux: boolean
    }
}

// test has no type errors
let test: DeepNullable<Foo> = {
    foo: null,
    bar: {
        baz: [{quz: null}, {quz: null}],
        qux: null
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgHIFcA2qCGAjVEA8AKgHxQC8UBUEAHsBAHYAmAzlAGLL0DGwAlgPb0AUFFFQA-BRFiAXBSq0GLKAEEATmowg8vegDMIaqAFUi00ZID6cBCnTZc6zdtPmocyjTpNW-LACsIHjcrGyQ0TBwIAHkAoOBCMzF3eQAfKHoIgG4hIV06NT0MLmhreHD7KKctRIVvZWrtMLtI3ESSAG8AX1zQSCgy2wiHGLieWvIOqABtAAUoXSgAawgQfj0KAF05ZuGowjnNknTM9CgunN7waDZ+fjIoDrc9O7lMgFssQwAaNywMNRyJ7JZL-ABeckaeCmAEdkBCoMxgGpdABzc5JEGiOHUORYO64DDCZI9HpCAD05KgdCRUAAFhhWPR7n1oIY1Pw1MwhLhgNSIEiduUWiM8Ld+CRJs9XhkIr9QQCgW4FQjph04QjTqgut9Hhq3hEupt5VioDiDeg3KShEA)